# Why doesn't the 'bundle install --without production' command not require '--without production' after update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

Why doesn't the second command of

```
$ bundle install
```

not need

```
--without production
```

(As this is how it went in a tutorial, so I assume its correct)
What is happening/reasoning behind it not being needed?

From http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec-demo_users_resource

```
$ bundle install --without production
$ bundle update
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe it's because `bundler` creates a `.bundle/config` file inside your project's folder.  This file stores the `--without production` option for later execution so that you don't have to type it every time.

Comment: I can confirm this.
After running `bundle install --without production` I find `.bundle/config` with the following contents: `---\nBUNDLE_WITHOUT: production`

Answer (score 1):

When you run your bundle command on your development machine, it won't install the gems for use in your production environment.

See here: http://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html

```
NAME
bundle-install - Install the dependencies specified in your Gemfile

SYNOPSIS

bundle install [--binstubs[=DIRECTORY]] [--clean] [--full-index] [--gemfile=GEMFILE] [--jobs=NUMBER] [--local] [--deployment] [--no-cache] [--no-prune] [--path PATH] [--system] [--quiet] [--retry=NUMBER] [--shebang] [--standalone[=GROUP[ GROUP...]]] [--trust-policy=POLICY] [--without=GROUP[ GROUP...]]
```