# Groups of gems in Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code in Bundler:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

As you can see I use mysql2 on production only. Now I'm developing my app on my local machine, but I get the following error:

```
Could not find mysql2-0.3.15 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But I don't want to do it, I need production gems only on production VPS. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: seems fine ..can you please paste your whole gem file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the [option](http://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_install.html#without). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145162/why-doesnt-the-bundle-install-without-production-command-not-require-wit) too (it saves the option so you only have to specify it once)

```
bundle install --without production
```